# Записи в базу mysql не заносятся

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, apache

Столкнулся с проблемой при переноске сайта на vds ubuntu. Вот в чем проблема - записи из уже готовой базы данных выносятся на ура. но заносится не хотят. Подключение к базе данных 100% верное ибо записи как уже говорилось ранее выносятся. на предыдущем хостинге записи спокойно добавлялись. щас же почему-то возникла такая проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Так я обнаружил проблему. оказывается в моем бд стоял режим MySQL strict.

Оператор INSERT здесь оставил некоторые столбцы таблицы пустыми, и в результате строгий режим отклоняет весь insert. Изменение режима непосредственно перед командой insert было более быстрым способом обойти проблему, чем обновление команды insert

Для отключения:

```
$strict = "SET sql_mode = ''";
mysqli_query($CONNECTDB, $strict);
```

Спасибо посту - [Why is MySQL INSERT statement not working without error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42613360/4827341)